# Duvidas sobre strings

Tags: c

Tenho a proposta de imprimir em um bilhete de teatro, 
a data, a hora, nome da peça (a ser digitado e lido por scanf) e a numero da poltrona do cliente,

```
// declaração da variável.

char PecaTeatral[255];
// pulando para a leitura da string 

switch(n){      
case 1:

printf("\nNome da peca teatral\n");

scanf("%s", PecaTeatral);

printf("DATA : %s HORA: %s\nPeca : %s \t\t numero da poltrona: %d", __DATE__, __TIME__, PecaTeatral, ingresso_inicial); 

break;

// imprimi o ingresso do cliente, apos vendido
```

...

a dificuldade nisto tudo, como consigo imprimir um texto, pois o atual código armazena uma palavra,

Answer (score 1):

Poderá usar o `scanf` ou o `fgets`, as mais "famososas" e que servem perfeitamente para leres uma frase, em vez de uma palavra.

- **Scanf**: Terá de acrescentar o `[^\n]`, para aceitar todo o tipo de caracteres, menos o botão enter.
  Deverá usar tambem o maximo numero de caracteres que quer ler `%51[^\n]`, vai ler no maximo 51 caracteres neste exemplo.

Ex: `scanf("%254[^\n]s", PecaTeatral);`

- **fgets**: Este exemplo é mais facil e a mais recomendada, pois consegue ler uma frase e limitar caracteres sem precisar de fazer grandes truques.

Ex: `fgets(PecaTeatral,254, STDIN);`

---

É possivel resolver o problema com a função `gets`, porem esta função é extremamente perigosa. Caso defina como:

`char PecaTeatral[10];`
e o utilizador escreva mais que `9 caracteres` o programa vai dar bug,